# Sailsjs - Model has no method 'save'

Tags: node.js, sails.js

```
User    
.find()
.where({ id: userId })
.then(function(user) {
    ...
    user.save(function(err) { console.log(err); });
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

The code above will generate an type error: 'Object [object Object] has no method 'save'. How to get rid of the error and save the model ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even if the code seems ok, there is a small issue: find returns an array and the returned error won't have the 'save' method. In order for this to work, you have to replace find with findOne.

This error doesn't look like it's important, but I have encountered it a few times.

```
User    
.findOne()
.where({ id: userId })
.then(function(user) {
    ...
    user.save(function(err) { console.log(err); });
})
.fail(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```